# Onclick event handler is executed several times when I click on a link

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an event handler that is called six times when I click on a link.

```
var elems = elem.getElementsByTagName('a');
var cntr = 0;
for(var a in elems) {
  AttachEvent(elems[cntr], 'click', function(e) {
    this.reporturl = this.href;
    document.getElementById('reportpopup').style.visibility = "visible";
    return false;
  });
}
```

I am using Firefox 3.5 currently so this is used for `AttachEvent`:

```
function AttachEvent(obj,evt,fnc,useCapture){
    if (!useCapture) useCapture=false;
    if (undefined == obj || null == obj) 
        return;
    if (obj.addEventListener){
        obj.addEventListener(evt,fnc,useCapture);
        return true;
    } else if (obj.attachEvent) return obj.attachEvent("on"+evt,fnc);
    else{
        MyAttachEvent(obj,evt,fnc);
        obj['on'+evt]=function(){ MyFireEvent(obj,evt); };
    }
}
```

The `this.href` value is the same each time, and there are only three links that match my `getElementsByTagName`.

So, I have attached an event to my link, and when I click on one of the three, it is called six times with the exact same link information.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're attaching the same event handler to the 0th item for as many times as there are links.

```
var cntr = 0;
    for(var a in elems) {
        AttachEvent(elems[cntr], 'click', function(e) {
                          ^never changes?
```

Secondly, in JavaScript object members, properties, array elements, etc. are all in the same collection. `for(var item in obj)` will run once for every available member of `obj`. If it is an array with 3 elements, it will run once for each element, once for the length property, and once each for... whatever the other two built-in properties are. That's six times total, which is probably not what you want. Use `for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)` for reliability.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to increment my cntr.